# edit location using mapbox ios7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mapbox

Is `mapbox` providing any feature to **edit or add location annotations** using `mapbox` iOS SDK??

If yes where the edited or added informations will be stored??(is it stored in `mapbox` services like google maps )

should i use  developer `mapid` for all users whoever is using my app or i have to get the users `mapid`

if you suggest any sample tutorial it would be great

[I referred this but i am not clear](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/#//api/name/updating%22Reffered%22)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/):

- `RMAnnotation` lets you add annotations to the map.
- Map ID refers to the map style if you are hosting the map imagery with Mapbox.

The docs page also links to sample projects and example code snippets.

Comment: Do we have to maintain our own server for storing the edited maps